# Как в Spinner можно к списку добавить поле ввода?

Tags: android

Добрый день, подскажите как можно в Spinner не только выбирать из списка, но и что то своё прописывать как в ComboBox ?

Comment: возможно вам подойдет `AutoCompleteTextView`? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Comment: @metalurgus очень близко, но не то, мне не для поиска среди фраз. Есть список установленных фраз, пользователь смотрит в выпадающий список и если ничего не походит,  пишет что то своё если подходит то выбирает.

Comment: Для этого AutoCompleteTextView тоже можно использовать ,если его переделать немного. Или еще можно SearchView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Библиотека на Github. Вроде то, что вам надо. [тык](https://github.com/xyxyLiu/Edit-Spinner)

Использовать так:

```
<com.reginald.editspinner.EditSpinner
        android:id="@+id/edit_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:dropDownDrawable="@drawable/spinner_icon"
        app:dropDownDrawableSpacing="15dp"
        app:dropDownDrawableWidth="25dp"
        app:dropDownDrawableHeight="25dp"
        />
```

---

```
mEditSpinner = (EditSpinner) findViewById(R.id.edit_spinner);
ListAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.your_string_array));
mEditSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```